# Java equivalent to ASP.NET global.Asax

Tags: java, global-asax

Hi I am new to java and I am developing a java web application i would like to run some code at application start up.
In .Net i would use the global.asax file, how can i do this in java.

Thanks for any help

Comment: if it's a webapp, what exactly are you implying by "application startup" ? when the application server starts up ? when your first servlet starts up ? please clarify

Comment: when i deploy my web application to the server. I would like to know what my options are. the best thing would be if this code ran before anything servlet was served.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I prefer to implement a listener for initialization, but that is just me.  Extend `javax.servlet.ServletContextListener` then configure your listener class in the `web.xml` file.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly, What you're looking for is `web.xml` (What is called Deployment Descriptor). There are many examples on Google that can show you how.

For "application startup", you would have to write a servlet that initializes your application (but I'm unclear as to what you mean "run code at application startup").

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.
I can use:

    <servlet>
 <display-name>ProcessServlet</display-name>
 <servlet-name>ProcessServlet</servlet-name>
 <servlet-class> Main.ProcessServlet</servlet-class>
 <load-on-startup>0</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

Could this be done with a regular class and not a servlet?

Comment: No, anything written in `web.xml` must follow the web descriptor specification. You can create a filter if you don't want to use servlets.